# Error while porting pages through Content Porter - "The following items are used in a child Publication"

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I am performing a Content Port operation from one Tridion server to another. I have ported Schemas, Components, TBBS, CTs and PTs. Now When I am trying to import the Pages I am facing few errors.  I am using Content Porter 2009 SP1 version.

Error details:

```
(TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  
(Cause=true)  The following items are used in a child Publication: Component 'Checkout-flow-offer (x)',Component 'Checkout-flow-subscription (x)'
(Cause=false)  Unable to save Publication (tcm:0-182-1).
(Callstack)  Request.SaveItem - Publication.Save - XMLState.Save - Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Update(UserContext,String) - Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save() - Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs) - Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) - Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) - Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.AssertBlueprintConflicts()
(TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
(TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
(TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  
(Cause=true)  The following items are used in a child Publication: Component 'Checkout-flow-offer (x)',Component 'Checkout-flow-subscription (x)'
(Cause=false)  Unable to save Publication (tcm:0-182-1).
(Callstack)  Request.SaveItem - Publication.Save - XMLState.Save - Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Update(UserContext,String) - Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save() - Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs) - Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) - Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) - Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.AssertBlueprintConflicts()
(TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
(TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
(TCMDAL::TCMItem::Update)  Error while updating item '/webdav/myPublication'
```

Could some one help explain the error?

As I have already ported all dependencies for a page, is there any simple way to resolve this?

Comment: Most important part about using Content Porter is: know what you are trying to do. Check what you are exporting and want to import, could you manually do that? Always remember, Content Porter cannot perform magic, it is usually only faster in creating/updating items than you manually can.

Comment: It looks as though you are missing a dependency in a child publication ("The following items are used in a child Publication"). How are you Content Porting? One publication at a time, or multiple?

Comment: @JoshHebb. I am just importing some pages in one publication at a time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like [premkumar subramanian's answer says](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3385/88), the logs raise an error on saving a publication item. Try importing with the **Dependency Filters** set to exclude everything.

[image]

The dependency filter setting makes sure only those items which you select (the pages) are imported. This also means you need to make sure that all dependencies of the pages you are importing are in the target system. When you missed some dependencies Content Porter will complain.

From your question it looks like you are importing all items one by one, this is [the right way to go](http://monicamanzano.blogspot.nl/2012/12/moving-items-around-within-single.html) indeed.

Remember that Content Porter is designed to port schemas, template and other building blocks to facilitate deploying changes in an DTAP street. It is not a tool for content migration.

Comment: +1 to the answer, though I think (some) content *migration* is a valid use case for Content Porter, typically to get "production" content in lower environments for testing. It's challenging, however, to achieve complete content *synchronization*, simply because any non-trivial content model has plenty of dependencies (in this case it looks like a publication issue). I'm probably nitpicking terminology, though (migration vs. synchronization). :-)

Answer (score 7):

The error message says that saving the Publication was not successful. But your objective was to port the pages.

Pls. make sure that you selected only those items which you wanted to content port.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Could you help me what filters that I have to apply while exporting and importing. it would be great if you could also tell what to exclude while export and import.

Comment: You may notice in the content porter interface that while selecting the item(s) under a Publication, the Publication itself is also automatically selected as one of the items to be content portered. If you don't want the Publication properties to be changed, you may right click on the Publication and select 'Selected Children only'. This will deselect the Publication.

Answer (score 5):

in your statement

> I am just importing some pages in one publication at a time

The error log indicates your settings are (at the very least) also attempting to import the respective Components (probably) attached to the Pages. Assuming you've considered the implications of 'creating' content in the parent Publication(s)...

The line

```
(Cause=true)  The following items are used in a child Publication: Component 'Checkout-flow-offer (x)',Component 'Checkout-flow-subscription (x)'
```

is very interesting also. I've seen a similar error when the Components where localized in a child publication, renamed in the parent and then a Content Port attempted at the parent - thus trying to create parent Components when 'child' components exist (all happening as expected as Content Porter uses the WebDAV paths and not IDs).

I'd certainly want to look at the relationship of the reported components with the pages and child/parent sharing/localization in the target system - perhaps you can add a little more detail regarding these.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will look once at my components again.