# Content Porter Fails for Localized Pages

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, localization

I'm using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 with Content Porter 2009 SP1 & (tried in SP2 as well)

I have a child website publication which inherits from a parent website publication. All pages are inherited into the child publications. When I export the Pages through content porter without localizing, they get exported without any issues.

But, when the pages are localized to update certain metadata for a different language, I'm consistently encountering an issue.

Item `/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg` failed export.

Should it be skipped?

Detail of the error message:

```
(TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  <no description>
(TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
(TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
(TCMDAL::TCMItem::Read)  Error while reading item **'/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg'**
```

Below is the extract from the content porter log:

```
2/12/2014 4:23:43 PM    [Information]    Going to export (with dependencies) item **'/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg'** 
2/12/2014 4:23:43 PM    [Verbose]           >>> Enter: ExporterBL::Exporter::ExportItemWithDependencies
2/12/2014 4:23:43 PM    [Verbose]                                           --- Param 'ItemUrl' = **/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg**
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Error]   Failed to export item **'/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg'** 
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Error]   (TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  <no description>
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Error]   (TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Error]   (TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Error]   (TCMDAL::TCMItem::Read)  Error while reading item **'/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg'** 
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Information]    Item **'/webdav/<child publication>/Root/<page>.tpg'**  moved to 'Failed list'
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Verbose]           <<< Exit: ExporterBL::Exporter::ExportItemWithDependencies
2/12/2014 4:23:59 PM    [Information]    Process successfully completed
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the Publication or Site setup. Can someone help me to resolve the problem?

**Edit 2/13/2014 9:30am IST** Please note, I have another local environment which exports the localized data properly. This issue happens only on couple of remote environments to which I have limited developer access.

Thanks,
Anbu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you like to check if on the local environment where the things are working have this hot-fix applies - `CP_3.1.0.75095 - Cumulative Hotfix`. You can get more details about this hotfix [HERE](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/ContentPorter_2009_SP1/index.aspx)

Apparently it seems to be a known issue with CP 2009 SP1 and in my case this issue got resolved once I applied the above said hot fix.

Comment: Glad that it has fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you are facing this issue on the environments where you have limited access. It could be related to security permissions against the user account with which you are running the content porter.
Also I can see in logs “Error while reading item”. So it adds to it as well.

To Port the localized page, the user(or user group) must have Page, Component, Folder and Structure Group Management Rights on that publication.
(I assume here that dependents are being ported as well)
Also check if the user(or user group) has Read, Write and Localize permissions on the structure group where your are porting the localized pages.

It could be helpful if you compare the user rights on local environment with remote environment. And adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh for your reply. The user was able to localize and make changes to the Structure Groups and Pages and able to make changes to the content - mainly the metadata for the other language. So the user has read & write permissions to the Pages and Structure groups. The same user was able to Export these pages from the parent publication and new pages created in the child publication.

Comment: I guess, you are porting the item with dependents. Try importing with the Dependency Filters set to exclude everything. also in smaller batches like one for each publication. this [link](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/error-while-porting-pages-through-content-porter-the-following-items-are-used) could be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to export one or two items from the Child publication without exporting all together. Also, applied all filters before exporting. The result is same - failed.